cannot insert to Supabase table with RLS and policy enabled
I have a table called petition with RLS enabled and the following two policies on it:
INSERT

Enable insert for authenticated users only

Applied to:authenticated role

SELECT

Enable read access for all users

Applied to:public role

I am able to do authenticated sign-in on my app and am able to write to table just fine when RLS is disabled.
Here is the precise error message returned:
Error creating petition: new row violates row-level security policy for table "petition"

also, here is my code:
    const { data, error } = await supabase
      .from("petition") // Replace with your table name
      .insert([
        {
          title: formData.title,
          recipient: formData.recipient,
          problem: formData.problem,
          solution: formData.solution,
          authorId: userId,
        },
      ])
      .select();


I don't know why someone thinks that my question is not well researched or not useful but what I can tell you is that all of the solutions to this problem have pointed to supabase automatically doing a read after a write. I don't think that is a problem for me because I've already enabled read access for all users. I'll go ahead and add the exact error message in case that helps.

I was able to fix my issue by changing the way that I was creating supabase client.
I had been doing:
import { supabase } from "../../../lib/supabaseClient";
instead of importing the following helper created after following official docs:
import { createClient } from "@/utils/supabase/client";
after that, I was able to create supabase client by doing:
const supabase = createClient();
and now my authenticated inserts work without error.
The previous utility that I was using had failed to pass auto token correctly, from what I understand.
